# Launching a cmd window with commands using python script?

Tags: python, cmd

How do I launch a cmd window and input the commands i specify into the cmd for windows using a python script?

For example , the script will launch the cmd and input the following : runas /username:Admin control

Then cmd will then prompt the user for their passwords and open the control panel.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/646543)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.call(['runas', '/username:Admin', 'control'])
```

Don't have a python shell here to test, but this should get you pretty close to what you want.

It should run the `runas` command which will prompt you for the password, then launch the control panel. This could easily be done with a batch program too, or even just a shortcut. Just putting that out there.

---

#### controlpanel.bat

This one is most comparable to your python script, but it skips having to load the pyton interpreter.

```
runas /username:Admin control
```

---

#### shortcut

This one lets you have a little more control over the command, and who is running it.
*right click desktop

*new

*shortcut

*Enter "runas /username:Admin control" for the Location.

*Type a name for the shortcut.

---

#### alternative shortcut

This one is useful if you just want UAC to handle it.

- same as above, but for location type just "control"
- then right click on the new shortcut, and click properties.
- click the shortcut tab
- click "advanced"
- check the "run as administrator" box.

---

#### Bonus alternative

This gives you a master list of all settings you can change, rather than just the control panel.

- Create a new folder, and rename it to:

  Settings.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
- You can change the "Settings" part to anything you want
- follow the instructions above for "alternative shortcut"